# I have a positive lookbehind Safari error

Tags: javascript, regex, safari

Hi guys I have a small issue with Regex that doesn't work in safari.

This is the problem:

```
Title = "Level 5 All programmes"
```

I am trying to separate it with positive lookbehind to keep the number in the first item of array like this:

```
Title.split(/(?<=[0-9])/)
```

And I get this

```
["Level 5", " all specialisation"]
```

Which is good, but the problem is that this solution doesn't work in Safari.

Do you guys have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Can you show what Safari does in this case? What is the outcome?

Comment: SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match and capture the parts with `/(.*?\d+)(\s.*)/` regex:

```js
var Title = "Level 5 All programmes";
var rx = /(.*?\d+)(\s.*)/;
var m = Title.match(rx);
if (m) {
  console.log("First part: '" + m[1] + "'\nSecond part: '"+ m[2] + "'");
}
```

The `/(.*?\d+)(\s.*)/` regex matches

- `(.*?\d+)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible and then 1+ digits
- `(\s.*)` - Group 2: a whitespace char followed with any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

To match across lines, replace `.` with `[^]` or `[\s\S]`.

For the cases when there is no second part, make the second group optional and when getting a match, check if Group 2 value is not `undefined`:

```js
var Title = "Level 5";
var rx = /(.*?\d+)(\s.*)?/;
var m = Title.match(rx);
if (m) {
  console.log("First part: '" + m[1] + "'");
  if (m[2] !== undefined) console.log("Second part: '"+ m[2] + "'");
}
```

Comment: Amazing man, I owe you a beer! But for example if I get a string like "Level 5" without second word after the number that won't be on a place of m[1] but on m[0]. Is there a way to make sure that it's always there?

Comment: Actually in case of string being "Level 5" it producess NULL

Comment: @Marko  Use `(.*?\d+)(\s.*)?`, I updated the answer.